# Passing global Windows keystrokes to AIR for Desktop for my custom game stream overlay

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, winapi, air

I am working on an app that animates by reacting to keystrokes I make while gaming. There are a fair number of 'show which key I press on the screen' apps out there for presentations, tutorials and streaming overlays, but I want to display my own animations based on the keys pressed rather than just the name of the key pressed.

I've searched the forums here, and it appears that AS3 / ActionSript / Adobe AIR for Desktop cannot get these when out of focus?  In that case, I am hoping for a companion 'applet' that will capture keystrokes and pass them to my AIR for Desktop app through an API.

If there was a way to get only those that were being pressed while a specific application - a game - was in focus, that would be even better.  This is for my own use and I am not planning to log someone else's keystrokes (and if I were, I would be an idiot to try to write it myself in AIR - searching for a solution to this has turned up many better key-loggers than I could ever write).

---

Off-topic:

TO YOU MEMBERS THAT DOWN VOTE BY DEFAULT, apparently because you already know everything about everything and think that I did not research enough or I would know it too:  how many hours/days/weeks of search and research do you consider enough before I can ask a question here?

I spent several hours looking through through AIR extensions, searching github and going through other assorted legitimate keylog apps including watching assorted product or how-to vids to try to find an answer.  And I searched stackoverflow thoroughly and read multiple posts and replies on similar questions before posting here. My question is carefully written, not identical to any other questions I found, and only asked after my own research had no conclusive answer, but clearly you want something more?

I know there are questions posted by people that are lazy or way out of their depths and just want a free ride, but it feels like adown vote is more or less a default response to all posts.

I love the idea of stackoverflow and on other sites and forums, I too have moderated, helped answer questions and contributed. But I rarely post here because I almost always come away feeling inadequate and belittled, and I see the same negativity and judgment on other member posts across the site.

Comment: A c++ native extension could work. But it's not really worth the effort. A quick and dirty solution would be a simple websocket server and an additional app that does the actual keylogging.

Comment: Can you compile `C#` code? If yes, then a companion app (is windowless, but shows in **Task Manager**) could be made in C#. Use the `FindWindow` and `sendKeys` commands. Your AIR app side could then run the C# tool (as an **.exe** file) using the **NativeProcess** API where it receives feedback via **std in/out**...

Comment: OK, so if sounds like if AIR initiated the C++ / C# app, then it could get the feedback efficiently.  I am not familiar with C++ / C# myself, not since a long time ago..

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to get started then, it's always nice to learn new things :-) And concerning your edit, you probably should post that on meta because it's more suited there and will actually lead to a discussion.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the replies (and have copied them over for finding a freelancer).  I did not know there was a place where stackexchange could discuss stackexchange.  I'm 'afraid' to participate though and lose rep, I am actually surprised my question lasted here this long. I finally got far enough to actually add comments. I could not even comment on my own questions before!  I sincerely appreciate the members here who sincerely want to help others, giving of their own free time to encourage learning and development of skills, and have nothing against you. But this system is flawed.

Comment: The rep for meta doesn't affect your rep on SO, afaik. I agree that the SE system itself has massive flaws (voting being completely useless for one), but this isn't really the place to talk about it.

Comment: @s1972 I recommend you download **SharpDevelop** (it's a lightweight-ish `C#` IDE/compiler). If you can install it and then successfully run a basic _"Hello World"_ test, then I can help you with the rest... Let me know using `@vc.one` in comments to notify me.

Comment: @vc.one That is most generous of you and I will take you up on that.  I have installed SharpDevelop and successfully compiled the command line / console 'Hello World!'. I am not in a rush, so I look forward to your help, but at your convenience.

Comment: @VC.One If your offer stands, I would still be interested in creating this little app. Thanks. (I think my previous reference to your ID wasn't case-accurate.)

Comment: @s1972 sorry for late reply. I don't mind helping if you still need it. The easiest code (meaning _not longest_) would involve having a controller app (C#) that sends your gaming inputs (keyboard?) to both window of game and Flash window (thus both things respond to same keyboard input at same time). Let me know if you're interested.